# xvfb electron : Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

Tags: linux, npm, electron, xvfb

Hello at all Stack Overflow community

I come today to ask experts.
I'm trying to make this browser https://github.com/minbrowser/min/
run from server without graphic card.
I've opened a topic on github https://github.com/minbrowser/min/issues/1753
I've tried many attemps of :
npm run build && xvfb-run node_modules/.bin/electron . --disable-gpu --use-gl=swiftshader -e -h --ignore-blanks --disable-software-rasterizer --headless

with many attemps with differents --options
but nothing want to work.

Someone can help me ?

Best regards
Thanks at all community for your support and the gread responses i've already find with you.